# Set fontSize in GUI.Button proportional to rectangle height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to run my unity application on different devices with different screen resolutions. If I run my code on a QHD smartphone, it's almost impossible to read the fixed fontSize.
I would like to calculate and set the fontsize exactly to have the fontheight in pixel fitting into my button rectangle.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the fontsize is in pixels (unlike the normal points).
For each user Element you have to get the style from the current skin with GUI.skin.GetStyle().

You just have to get/and set the font size in the style:

```
        GUIStyle style2 = GUI.skin.GetStyle("window"); //get current Style for windows
        style2.fontSize = (int)((float)windowRect.height/12);//modify the font height
        windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, DialogWindow, "Restart Game?",style2);//specify the modified style in the Window
```

In my case I had to do this for my window, label and button:

```
GUIStyle style3 = GUI.skin.GetStyle("label"); //get label style
style3.fontSize = (int)((float)windowRect.height / 16); //modify fontSize
GUI.Label(new Rect(5, y, windowRect.width, windowRect.height/10), "This will delete saved data!",style3) //create label with modified style
```

You can also set the default button style rather than specifying the modified style in each button:

```
    GUIStyle style=GUI.skin.GetStyle("button"); //get current button style
    style.fontSize = (int)((float)windowRect.height / 12); //modify the fontSize relatively
    GUI.skin.box = style;//modify the default style

GUI.Button(new Rect(5, y, windowRect.width - 10, windowRect.height / 10), "Restart")//will take the modified default style
GUI.Button(new Rect(5, y, windowRect.width - 10, windowRect.height / 10), "Cancel")
```